# Laravel 5.4 A facade root has not been set

Tags: php, laravel, upgrade, laravel-5.4

This error is driving me crazy. 
I had Laravel 5.2, then I upgraded to 5.3 and then 5.4 then this error started to appear.
I have searched everywhere on Google and here in SO but none of the solutions is working on my case. Any idea what to do?

[image]

Comment: Your error says something about `Metatag`. What package are you using to set your page `<title></title>`;

Comment: im using this: https://github.com/Torann/laravel-meta-tags

however it seems to me there should be something up with recofnising or initiating Fascades, (yes/no)?

because it can't get the fascade instance and therefore can't use the MetaTag::set method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did have a look that the package you provided. Their last commit was in October 2016. So I can say, this does not support Laravel 5.4 yet.

The latest version you can use this package in is Laravel 5.3. Open an issue for the package manager to add support for Laravel 5.4.

I installed it in a clean Laravel 5.4 project and it didnt work as well, though I received a different error. You said it works in 5.3, so I think it's just a matter of version support.

Comment: yep, the whole upgrade thing started because I wanted to install Socialite package and it required Laravel 5.4. Laravel 5.4 required a whole other bunch of packages to be upgraded etc etc.

So right now, just a few minutes ago I managed to install Socialite 2.0.20 with laravel 5.2 (so don't need upgrade). 

I would love to have the latest versions of course but I think I'll stick with these for now. Thanks for the info & insights ;)